# Smartpools' sha3_512, is there a stand alone implementation?

Tags: hash, sha3, hash-algorithm

Smart pool has implemented `sha3_512` ([contract](https://github.com/SmartPool/contracts/blob/develop/contracts/Ethash.sol)), tough it looks like it is combined with EthHash. Is there a stand alone library just for the `sha3_512` function?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74085/discussion-on-question-by-miyamoto-smartpools-sha3-512-is-there-a-stand-alone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sha3_512 library on

https://github.com/yaronvel/solidity-sha3-512/blob/master/contracts/SHA3_512.sol

that supports messages up to 64 bytes